# graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<token> returns "Cannot call API on behalf of this user"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

Receiving an OAuthException when:

> curl https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=

but only when I curl from my AWS-based web server. If I run the exact same command from my local machine, it works and returns the expected result.

Also, users who are designated as administrators of the Facebook App work as expected. It's only non-administrators that seem to have this restriction.

Is there some IP-based filtering I'm not aware of? Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. This was likely caused by the July 10 breaking changes to the Facebook API. Fixed it by removing the country restriction in the App's Advanced settings.

Comment: Add your comment as answer and accept it, so people in future may get solve issue similar to your's easily.