# 'Cannot call API on behalf of this user' on FB API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am having trouble with facebook API call. I am using Koala for server side api call but recently came into issue making api call. So I tried to bypass koala call and did raw api http call using call but to no avail.

When I do curl from development machine it works fine.

`curl "https://graph.facebook.com/me?oauth_token=my_token`

It returns profile details, but the same thing done from production machine, it's throwing the exception

`{"error":{"message":"Cannot call API on behalf of this user","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

Does anyone had the same issue? Like to hear from you guys.

Comment: Guys found the solution. Might have been due to July breaking changes. Just removed location filter from app's advanced setting and it did worked.
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327121/graph-facebook-com-meaccess-token-token-returns-cannot-call-api-on-behalf-of

Comment: Hi, there!  I may be having the same issue.  I'm curious, though, if you had this issue in May, how could it be due to the July breaking changes?  Had you enabled the breaking changes before they went into effect in July?

Comment: My mistake, it must have been due to feb breaking changes (but not sure which specific breaking changes did it). And yes all changes were in effect when I had that issue.

Answer (score 6):

I found the source of the problem (on our site, at least).  In Facebook's developer console (https://developers.facebook.com/apps), our app was showing an invalid privacy policy.  Due to this, Facebook had automatically placed our app into Sandbox Mode.

**Updating our privacy policy and (more notably) removing our app from Sandbox Mode caused this error to cease.**

Other users seem to have had some success with removing regional (country-specific) restrictions on who can and cannot log in to their app (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-social-auth/XaE5dFXEqhA)

Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the App in dev mode. All I did was **remove the subscription & resubscribe** my webhook server and this worked for me.