# SecureSocial : fillProfile fails during Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I'm using Play! 2.0.4 with SecureSocial to handle Facebook connect.

With an account that was successfully connecting some days ago, Facebook answers the server with an error, which is thrown here :

https://github.com/aogriffiths/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/FacebookProvider.scala#L65

The error :

```
{"error":{"message":"Cannot call API on behalf of this user","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I thought the token has expired. But a new one is generated at each try to connect.

How can I handle this error ?

Cordially,
Julien

Comment: Are you accessing something that may have been removed from the API with one of the breaking changes? Are the permissions still vaid? How does the call look like? What are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was indeed related to the breaking changes. 
We found someone with the same problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334451/cannot-call-api-on-behalf-of-this-user-on-fb-api-call

Comment: I will create an anwer for it so you can accept it if you like ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To make it acceptable here my answer from the comments:*

These messages are sometimes due to breaking changes somewhere on the Facebook roadmap. Be sure to check all the changes for the current month and your app settings if you have enabled/disabled any of them.