# Unexpected "Cannot call API on behalf of this user" after upgrading to graph api 2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We've allowed sign up/access to our website using Facebook Login for a long time. Two days ago, after upgrading to graph api 2.10, this stopped working for *a portion* of our users. Myself and most others are unaffected.

The error message received in the Access Token response reads "Cannot call API on behalf of this user".

I can't find anything in the 2.9 -> 2.10 changelog that mentions anything remotely connected to this problem, and I've found very little on this issue externally.

A few posts suggests that it might have something to do with insufficient privacy policy settings in our Facebook app settings, but everything is in place expect the non-mandatory Data Deletion Request URL. The fact that it also works perfectly fine for me as an EU citizen (affected by GDPR) says to me that it's something else. We do not have any country restrictions in place, and those who are affected by this comes from a variety of countries both inside and outside of the European Union.

Does anybody recognize this problem?

Comment: Does the problem go away, if the affected users completely remove your app from their FB settings, and then try to log in and grant the requested permissions again?

Comment: No. They can remove the app (even make a successful removal request from our website), but then they cannot reconnect with us.

Comment: @Jyrgomatic news? same issue..

Comment: @Berto99 Nothing new. On the other hand, I haven't had any complaints from our users lately either.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, also after an update (from 2.9 to 3.1). The fix for me was to remove location restrictions within the facebook console (**Settings > Advanced > App Restriction > Contry Restricted**):

[image: location restriction]

---

<sup>I got this idea from a comment on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16327121/6320039), and [this google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-social-auth/XaE5dFXEqhA).</sup>

Comment: Thanks. However, the country restriction has never been turned on for our app. There's something else, but the Facebook Team doesn't seem very keen on helping me figure out what :)

Comment: This helped! Not exactly like this, but it helped! The country restriction was off, I switched it on and added the "Use without location" option, now it works. Thank You, guys!

Comment: @zozzancs - nope, wrong again, this only worked temporally...

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/apis/FB-login-Reporting-API

sounds like the app type should be `Business`

today I meet this error, follow above document, I new create a business app, then error be resolved.